# rename sort field in elasticsearch output

Tags: elasticsearch

I am running the following query to get a list of shops within 5km from an orignal gps point, i am also adding the actual distance in the output through "sort":

```
GET /catalog_shop/shop/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : {
                "match_all" : {}
            },
            "filter" : {
                "geo_distance" : {
                    "distance" : "5km",
                    "location" : {
                        "lat" : 1.276129,
                        "lon" : 103.84744
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    },
 "sort" : [
      {
          "_geo_distance" : {
              "location" : {
                    "lat" : 1.276129,
                    "lon" : 103.84744
              }, 
              "order" : "asc",
              "unit" : "m"
          }
      }
  ]
}
```

it works but the result for the actual distance field is showing as:

```
"sort": [
  85.03849610942689
]
```

is there a way to rename the field "sort" by something customisable (for example "distance") and to change the result type from array to string ?

Comment: No, but that's something easily done in your client logic

Comment: in this case, is it possible to sort by something else than the distance but to still have the distance in the output?

Comment: Yes, using `script_fields`you can calculate the distance of each document to a given point and return it with each document.